# Como sobrescrever o método remove() do Iterator?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método

Eu criei um repositório (`RepositorioObjeto`) e ele implementa a interface `Iterator` sobre o objeto que o repositório armazena (`Iterator<Objeto>`). Por isso, tive que sobrescrever os métodos `next()`, `hasNext()` e `remove()`. Eu tive que adaptar o `next()`, pois ele apenas retorna o objeto (ou seja, não o incrementa, isso deixei para outro método porque tinha alguns métodos que precisava dar numa mesma iteração dois `next()`, fazendo com que se deslocasse para outro objeto). Segue o código do `next()` e `hasNext()`:

```
public Vendedor next(){
    Vendedor vendedor = this.vendedores.get(posicao);
    return vendedor;
}

public boolean hasNext(){
    boolean temProximo = true;//posto true pois comumente será mais vezes true
    if (posicao >= this.vendedores.size() || this.vendedores.get(posicao) == null) {
        temProximo = false;
        zerarContadorPosicao();
    }
    return temProximo;
}

public static void incrementarContadorPosicao(){
    posicao++;
}
```

OBS.: posição é um atributo estático

O grande problema que não sei como é quanto ao `remove()`, o que deve ser implementado? Pois o método de remoção [`removerVendedor`] do objeto (que é do tipo `Vendedor`), que segue logo abaixo, quero que se utilize do `remove()` que vem com o `Iterator`, tanto que chamo no método `removerVendedor`, mas para isso tem que se implementar, mas como, sem que haja redundância do código (repetição de código)?

```
public void removerVendedor(String cpfVendedor) throws NaoEncontradoVendedorException{
    boolean removeu = false;
    if (!cpfVendedor.equals("") && !cpfVendedor.equals(" ")){
        ListIterator<Vendedor> iVendedor = this.vendedores.listIterator();
        while(iVendedor.hasNext()){
            if (iVendedor.next().getCpf().equals(cpfVendedor)){
                iVendedor.remove();
                removeu = true;
                zerarContadorPosicao();
                salvarArquivo();
                break;
            }
            incrementarContadorPosicao();
        }
    }

    if (removeu == false){
        throw new NaoEncontradoVendedorException();
    }
}

@Override
public void remove() {  
}
```

Comment: É estranho que o next retorne o atual. Talvez exista um problema com a lógica disso. Tem como esclarecer essa parte?

Comment: Você terá dificuldades enquanto não resolver estes problemas: **a)** Você não deveria usar uma variável estática (*posicao*) para armazenar o estado do objeto pois ela não pertence a nenhum objeto. **b)** O *next* do *Iterator* deveria navegar até o próximo item e então retorná-lo, esta é a convenção do Iterator. **c)** Cada vez que um *Iterator* for solicitado, uma nova instância dele deve ser criada, assim você não terá problemas com a mesma lista sendo percorrida por dois consumidores distintos.

Comment: Quanto ao *remove*, o seu método existente remove por CPF, nada a ver com o *remove* do iterator, o qual remove o item da posição corrente. No *remove* do iterator você pode simplesmente chamar o *remove* da lista passando o índice corrente. Lembre-se é claro de validar a posição corrente e de mudá-la para o item anterior depois da remoção (ver respota do @ReginaldoSoares). Se você terminar com código redundante nos dois métodos, mova a parte repetida do código para um novo método a fim de reutilizá-lo tanto no *remove* do iterator quanto no método que remove por cpf.

Comment: @Caffé o meu repositório implementa o Iterator. MInha classe básica é Vendedor. E criei um repositório chamado RepositorioVendedor e implementei o Iterator<Vendedor>. O atributo posição é um atributo estático da classe RepositorioVendedor. O que vc disse continua válido (quanto ao static)? Outra coisa que não entendi foi que é afirmado que  next deveria ir até o próximo e retorná-lo, mas não é isso que estou fazendo? E, por fim, você está dizendo que tenho toda vez que precisar duas vezes um iterator, devo criar duas instâncias dele? Como controlar que ele não compare ele com ele mesmo?

Comment: @JNMarcos Sim, variável *static* continua não sendo adequada para manter a posição atual. Não, não é isso que você está fazendo - você mesmo escreveu que não incrementa no *next*, ao invés disso retorna o atual. Sim, se você precisa de dois *iterators*, deve criar duas instâncias (deve criar uma nova instância cada vez que um *iterator* for solicitado). Não entendi a última pergunta. Procure exemplos de implementação de *iterators*. É bastante simples - mantenha essa simplicidade. Se quiser, poste o restante do seu código relevante para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver seria:

```
@Override
public void remove() {  
      if(posicao <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("elementos indisponiveis!");
        }
        this.vendedores.remove(--posicao);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o porquê desse --posicao. Não deveria ser somente posicao,  já que incremento depois?

Comment: @JNMarcos pela referencia de implementação do seu código inferi que "posicao"nunca seria 0 visto que: posicao >= this.vendedores.size() ou seja posicao != index, provavelmente iniciada em 1. Por isso o teste de posicao <= 0 no override além do decremento previamente a remoção do elemento da lista pelo index.